# VS Code debug Attach using Process ID stopped working

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, attach-to-process

For some time I have been using VS Code to debug Python code connecting to Excel using pyxll. The procedure I have been using is:
Click the debug icon
Click "Run and Debug"
Select "Attach using Process ID Attach to a local process"
Select Excel from the list of processes displayed

Previously VS Code then connected to Excel and I could debug the associated Python code, but starting yesterday nothing happens after selecting Attach using Process ID Attach.

I have not changed any settings or installed new software (that I'm aware of) since the debug process was working.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling VS Code but this made no difference.

Comment: @Сергей Кох I really don't know how to be more specific.  I am trying to debug Python code running in a local process, the process being Excel using the pyxll add-in.  The procedure I used to use has stopped working.  After clicking "Run and Debug" and selecting "Attach using Process ID Attach to a local process" I used to get a list of locaal processes, but now I get nothing, and I see no way of connecting to the local process.

Comment: Have you tried to use the old version of python extension.

Comment: I have now uninstalled and reinstalled with older versions, with versions from 3 months and 6 months ago.  I also tried the pre-release version.  All work up to selecting the Debug Configuration, then nothing happens when I select "Attach using process ID Attach to a local process"

Comment: This problem has now resolved itself (18 Feb 2023).  The latest update to VS Code installed itself, and the debug process now works as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was having has now fixed itself (since 18 Feb 2023) with the latest update to VS Code.  The debug procedure for linking to a local process now works as before.  The Version is 1.75.1; details below:
[image]